# Make divs have a 20% width with padding in between each, but not to the left of the first or the right of the last

Tags: css, multiple-columns, css-selectors

Let's say I've got this layout to build:

[image]

Assuming the text and the grid are within the same div, and therefor share a width of about 990px, how can I dynamically make this grid have equal width columns, without fixed widths?

I could set each `div` to `width:20%`, but then they'd line up directly next to each other instead of spaced out. http://jsfiddle.net/97H3P/

I could set each `div` to `width: 20%`, `box-sizing: border-box`, and `padding: 0 20px`, but then there would be a 20px gap between the edge of the lines and the edge of the first and last `div`. http://jsfiddle.net/97H3P/1/

I could set up each `div` to `box-sizing: border-box;`, `width: 20%` and `padding-right: 20px`, and then on the 5th div, set `padding-right: 0;`, but then the fifth div is wider than the rest. http://jsfiddle.net/97H3P/2/

I could set the first four `div`s of each row to `box-sizing: border-box;`, `width:20.8%`, the fifth to `width: 16.8%`, and then `padding-right: 20px` to all of them, but that math only works out at the 990px width. http://jsfiddle.net/97H3P/3/

Is there a better way to do this? I can't find any elegant solution.

Thanks.

Update: For a few minutes, I was interested in CSS3's `column-count` feature, but then I realized it only does top to bottom, not left to right, which is how I need this ordered.

Comment: well. bootstrap does the trick. why haven't you tried to use it's grid system ?

Comment: You mean from getbootstrap.com? I've never worked with it before, and I've already got this site mostly built. I'm not seeing something like this in their components section anyway, do you have an example I can see?

Comment: have you heard of http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ calc(), check if you are ok with it's browser support.

Comment: @wlin That's actually perfect, but it needs to work in IE8+. Will look in to fallbacks. Thanks!

Comment: @wlin actually, screw it. IE8 users can have a bit of extra padding. Thanks! Post as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/jBgqE) a non-Boostrap example I've sketched quickly.

Even though it uses the Bootstrap classes.

The trick is achieved by using the `position: relative` and `box-sizing: border-box`

It is also kinda responsive.

Comment: Ah, I had thought about using `position: relative`, but for some reason couldn't put together to use it this way. Thanks, I may use this in the future. I ended up going with `width: calc(100% + 40px)`, for this one though.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at flexbox http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about how I could use Flexbox, but I couldn't figure out how to add a gap like this, without running in to the same problems. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

How about using some extra divs as spacers? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pyLg/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: #000;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    opacity: 0.2;
    width: 18%;
}

div.spacer{
    opacity: 1;
    width: 2.5%;
}
```